# JHipster - Can't reset user password

Tags: jhipster

Since JHipster use PasswordEncoder i can't as admin see what is my user password. He says he can't login and reset password is not working for him. Is there any way for me to set default password to him. I tried to copy hash of default 'admin' password and set it for him, but i still can't login ?

I tried to set twice same password for me and i got two different hash for same password ? How can JHipster decrypt when there are 2 hashes for same password ?

Answer (score 1):

JHipster uses `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to hash passwords, it uses BCrypt strong hashing function.

As a result, the `password_hash` column in `Users` table contains values that start with `$2a$10$` which states the algorithm and its cost followed by the 
salt and finally the hash itself.